# Image processing with layers in javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I'm making a website for a local printing company. One of the important requirements of the website is a customize page associated with every product. This page will be having an image of the product and user can upload his logo. This logo will then be presented over the image of the product.

User can move or resize his logo and there is also a textbox in which user can input the text he wants to be printed on the product.

As the user enters text it appears on the product image alongside the logo image he has previously uploaded.

This text should also be movable and and its size can be altered by selecting a font size from a drop down box.

I am thinking of some JavaScript image processing library which provides a support of "Photoshop like layers" but couldn't find any.

I have no clue how to do this. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: look I have product something like your... see source მaybe it is worth using...   http://standart.ge/kedi

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is something I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you tell me about the JavaScript/jquery plugin/library, you have used to implement it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it is jquery 1.7.1 and clean JS ... I do not think that you need some plugins it is not hard to do

Comment: use this source and add drags and resizes that's all

Comment: Thanks for your help maxART, I was also thinking about simple jQuery drag and resizes, but, what made me to think about some library or plugin is the fact that I need to save the final finished image as a jpeg file. Is there any way to save the final processed image as jpeg?

Comment: if you need save file on server you can not do this using JS... you need some server side language for example PHP...

Comment: you only can manipulate html object with image using JS and then send to server...